# Should all opinion-based questions be put On Hold?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, on-hold

I posted a question today that was a bit *odd* in terms of questions on SO. It was a little *vague* but I really needed help with it.

[**Question Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063080/better-way-to-create-text-based-game)

It has been put on hold due to "opinion-based" answers, but for this question I feel that is key to an "opinion-based" answer.

**How could I improve it to avoid being put on hold?**

This is something I am creating and I would like to get a view from anyone and everyone to see how they would take on a task such as this one. I believe that putting the question on hold is just stopping people from thinking of great ideas to share with other people that may be in the same boat as myself.

Its not like this is about code syntax, its about possible ways to complete a task. A task that has many options on how to complete it, yes in someone's option `x` it better then `y` but its then down to the OP to choose what they think is best for them. That's the point of being able to ask questions isn't it?

I would just like to know if anyone else feels the same way I guess. Any comments on the subject would be great to read.

Comment: Would be nice to know why the dowvote. I'm kinda new to this site I would like to improve my questions wherever possible. Also that was a downvote around 10 secs after I posted.. How could you and read this post and my question on SO in that time.

Comment: *It was a little vague but I really needed help with it.* Well, that justifies it of course :)

Comment: @juergend You should look at the question, I did everything I could to explain it etc. Every developer has that moment where you just get stuck. This was on of them moments, so where did I turn to.. SO as I know people there can be extremely helpful, and from the answers I got they were. Some very good ideas in there. Also this isn't just about my question, overall shouldn't some questions be allowed to be "opinion-based"?

Comment: That question is really an elaborate way of asking 'what programming language should I use'. Which is too opinion-based, doesn't have a correct answer so doesn't really fit with the scope of the site.

Comment: @JonW The question is nothing to do with "what language should I use". Not even a little bit. If that isn't clear then next time I ask a question I will be sure to add that in. Thank you.

Comment: I have to say this again. Another downvote without a comment explaining why? Is this the wrong area to post this kind of question because im kinda confused as to how this could get downvoted.

Comment: @Ruddy: Your question is: "What is a suitable method to code this game?". Regardless of what else you've written in there beforehand about what you've currently done your single question is not really any different to a 'what language should I use' post. I'm not saying you're asking for a language to use, just that the type of question asked is no different to people that do ask that.

Comment: Doesn't this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask answer your question already?

Comment: This isn't what im saying at all. You all seem to think im talking about my question alone. It was used as an example, I see questions all the time that et closed to "opinion-based". I feel this should be allowed on SO as for some questions its **key**. I don't see a problem in some cases for this to be allowed.

Comment: Opion-based however is exactly what SO is not. Fair questions to have as a developer, but it's explicitly what the site is not about.

Comment: @Ruddy: Try to be polite, nice, and remember that it's a privilege to use this community.

Comment: Would it make you happier if I voted to close as `Too Broad`??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it wasn't closed as *primarily opinion based* then it could have been closed as *too broad* - take your pick. This was determined by five of your peers, equally another five could vote to reopen it.

You've got a perfectly valid question, it's just not within the scope of Stack Overflow to answer it in it's current form. If you broke it down into small discrete problems then it would be more suitable. For example if you found a particular pattern that suits you could explore and try it then ask questions as you encounter them.

Comment: I see, thats the point tho. " if you found a particular pattern ", I couldn't. All of the ways I tried didn't work correctly or were messy etc. "too broad" is what I thought it would have be flagged as if anything. Again this isnt just about my question I was asking if all questions (such as this one) should be put "on hold". You said its a valid question and I agree its opinion based but I don't feel thats a reason to close it. The question is asking for it so answers should be allowed to be option based.  If this is not in the scope of SO is there somewhere else I should have gone?

Comment: @Ruddy You could potentially create a new question on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), if you do so you should try and keep the scope narrow, i.e. question how you could adapt whatever pattern to fit your scenario. Alternatively if you can narrow the scope sufficiently there is no problem why it cannot be posted on SO; as a suggestion try *"Pattern [xyz] doesn't quite do [y] when trying to do [game action] in [language]. Can I {adapt|munge|morph|combine another} pattern?"*. The key is to narrow the scope, isolate out smaller more discrete problems.

Comment: Interesting, Will come in handy next time I ask a question with such a wide scope. Thank you, very helpful answer. just another quick question for you. Why has this question been downvoted so hard, does this not belong here? Or is it because people read the title and disagree with it? Im pretty new to this site so would be nice to know, as 4 downvotes and not a single reason as to why.

Comment: @Ruddy Don't worry about that, [votes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Nothing to be concerned about. Generally it means that readers disagree with your question, not necessarily with the way it's written.

Comment: Erm, ok kinda odd but sure. its a little off putting to be honest lol. Never mind I will go back over to SO. Thanks for the answer!